# How to know From Xamarin.ios which Page is active

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, nfc

Any Solution to know if content page is active or called inside a AppDelegate.cs ?
because iv installed a plugin NFC, and i want to active the plugin only when NFC.xaml page is active, not when starting the application.
in this code am trying to begin session only When page NFC.xaml is active or called

````
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
     // if(App.Current==NFC.xaml) any way to know the content page ? 
          Session = new NFCNdefReaderSession(this, null, true);
          Session?.BeginSession();```

        }
    }
````

Comment: thanks for ur quick answer , how can i keep a reference ? i didnt understand ..

Comment: how to know the current page ?

Comment: in the AppDelegate .cs there is no (App.Current.MainPage)

Comment: ok, but it called just the first time ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a page is getting active [OnAppearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms) method would be triggered .

So we could use `MessagingCenter` here .

##### NFC.xaml.cs

```
  protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            MessagingCenter.Send<object>(this,"Hi");
        }
```

##### AppDelegate.cs

```
public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {

          MessagingCenter.Subscribe<object>(this, "Hi", (obj) =>
            {
                Session = new NFCNdefReaderSession(this, null, true);
                Session?.BeginSession();
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for ur solution , it solved the problem but instead of <object> i changed to Content page Nfc ,